# Консольный интерпретатор javascript

Tags: javascript, консоль

Доброго времени суток.
Не подскажите, существуют ли в природе такие? Хочется иметь возможность запуска сценария в консоли, без браузера. ОС - windows либо linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В линуксе есть, называется rhino (javascript движок для Java, но вполне работает в консоле).
Вот маленький пример кода (из демок)

```
// unique.js: read the contents of a file and print out the unique lines
defineClass("File")
// "arguments[0]" refers to the first argument at the command line to the
// script, if present. If not present, "arguments[0]" will be undefined,
// which will cause f to read from System.in.
var f = new File(arguments[0]);
var o = {}
var line;
while ((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
    // Use JavaScript objects' inherent nature as an associative
    // array to provide uniqueness
    o[line] = true;
}
for (i in o) {
    print(i);
}
```

Вполне может для поделок сгодиться:)

Также можно установить node.js и получить движок v8. Некоторые скажут, что это как с пушки по комарам, но

Comment: спасибо, похоже node.js то что надо

Answer (score 2):

Ну насчёт linux надо смотреть, а вот в виндах уже давное есть вещь, называемая windows scripting host (если склероз не изменяет) (WSH). Более десяти лет. Из коробки -- VBScript и JScript.

Comment: Пасибо не знал. А не подскажите этот WSH можно с какой либо ide запускать что бы иметь возможность пошаговой отладки и просмотра содержимого переменных ?

Comment: можно вполне V8 JavaScript Engine или node.js использовать